# How to do 3 way filtering/Grouping on Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Java list representation like below

**List representation of data**

```
[
    { "type" : "Error", "name" : "xyz" },
    { "type" : "Success", "name" : "abc" },
    { "type" : "none", "name" : "prq" },
    { "type" : "Success", "name" : "" },
    { "type" : "Success", "name" : "xyz" },
    { "type" : "Warning", "name" : "efc" }
    .
    .
    .
]
```

(Partial representation here).
and an Object representation below

```
public Node {
    List<String> errorNames;
    List<String> SuccessNames;
    List<String> WarningNames;
    }
```

I want to use Java streams to separate the three type of names based on their type and add each name to the respective Lists.

What will be the best way (Stream.filter/Collect/Map anything else) to split the list such that at the end "*Node's->(all the lists)*" will have corresponding data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Node` class actually looks something like this:

```
public class Node {
    private String type;
    private String name;

    public Node(String type, String name) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

You can use `Collectors#groupingBy` in combination with `Collectors#mapping` to create a `Map<String, List<String>>` where they key is the `type` and the value are the `List` of `name` for every `Node` of that `type`:

```
var nodes = List.of(
    new Node("Error", "xyz"), new Node("Success", "abc"),
    new Node("none", "prq"), new Node("Success", ""),
    new Node("Success", "xyz"), new Node("Warning", "efc")
);

var map = nodes.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Node::getType,
                        Collectors.mapping(Node::getName, Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{Warning=[efc], Error=[xyz], none=[prq], Success=[abc, , xyz]}
```

Comment: can you explain "collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Node::getType,
                        Collectors.mapping(Node::getName, Collectors.toList())));"

Comment: @NikulPadhya `Collectors.groupingBy` just groups `Node` objects by their `type` in this case, and `Collectors.mapping` changes the `Node` to its `name`.

Comment: @Jcob, Thanks a ton for the answer, I was able to get it working with the tip you gave in the original answer. I think I was looking for a filter method that can do either or filtering on the stream.